# How can i save a frame in a live video using opencv in python?

Tags: python, opencv, imutils

How to grab a fram from a live video using opencv?

I created a face recognition program using opencv and i want to capture an image when the confidence > 0.8
this is the code for initializing the liveVideo

```
 LiveVideo = VideoStream(src=0).start()
    while True:
        frame = LiveVideo.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=1000)
     ....
```

if anyone knows how to grab a frame from the live video and save it please tell me how to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [imwrite](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html) function from your opencv to extract the current frame.

You can also add [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) and convert it to string for naming purpose for the output file.

```
import time as t
LiveVideo = VideoStream(src=0).start()
        while True:
            frame = LiveVideo.read()
            timestr = t.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
            cv2.imwrite("frame%s.jpg" % timestr, frame )
```